# How do you add youtube links that start at a specific time?

Tags: support

I want to edit an old question of mine with a youtube link. For reference I want to add this link to start at 3:08.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRECArfFKhk

Answer (score 8):

Youtube offers very simple functionality to do this.

Click on the Share option on Youtube, and you are provided with the URL and a couple of boxes underneath to allow you to link directly to the desired timestamp. You can very easily do it manually though:

For example this video URL:

https://youtu.be/usgavULOhsc

Becomes this URL when I start at 2m14s

https://youtu.be/usgavULOhsc?t=2m14s

[image]

Comment: And yes, I'll admit to a shameless plug there :-)